# cfoot-first page of chapter not bold

Tags: chapters, bold

Footer of the first page of every chapter is not bold, but it should be. All the others are bold.

```
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
    \setlength{\headheight}{40pt}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
    \makeatletter
    \setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
    \makeatother
    \renewcommand{\topfraction}{1.0}
    \renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{1.0}
    \renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.0}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} 
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}} 
    \clubpenalty = 10000 
    \widowpenalty = 10000 
    \displaywidowpenalty = 10000 
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[EL]{\textsc{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[OR]{\textsc{\rightmark}} 
    \fancyhead[ER]{}
    \fancyhead[OL]{}
    \rfoot{}
    \lfoot{}
    \cfoot{\bf \thepage}
```

Comment: The first page of a chapter uses a different page style, not `fancy` of course, but `plain`, in a usual setup; your changes are not applied for this first page of a chapter then. You have either to say `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\cfoot{\textbf{\thepage}}` etc. or using more sophisticated tricks. Side note: `\bf` is a deprecated macro; use `\textbf{...}` instead

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : Thanks, it works! A "}" is missing at the end of your command :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your preamble:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} %
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}%
```